# Consolidate entries on swap level Pandas

Tags: pandas, swap

I swap levels on a multindex data frame and when the swap occurs I would like the the "like" entries in levels to be consolidated.

I've tried a simple dataframe.swap(i,j) and that swaps them but it does not perform the consolidation I want.

```
import pandas as pd

idx2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([("A5",6),("A5",1), ("A2",2),("A2",1),("A3",1),("A3",2), ("A4",4),("A4",1), ("A1",1),("A1",2)],
                                 names = ['first','second'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[10, 11, 7, 8, 5,1,2,3,4,5],  
                    "B":[21, 5, 32, 4, 6,1,2,3,4,5],  
                    "C":[11, 21, 23, 7, 9,1,2,3,4,5],  
                    "D":[1, 5, 3, 8, 6,1,2,3,4,5]},  
                    index = idx2)
```

`df2`

```
               A   B   C  D
first second
A5    6       10  21  11  1
      1       11   5  21  5
A2    2        7  32  23  3
      1        8   4   7  8
A3    1        5   6   9  6
      2        1   1   1  1
A4    4        2   2   2  2
      1        3   3   3  3
A1    1        4   4   4  4
      2        5   5   5  5
```

`df2.swap(0,1)`

```
               A   B   C  D
second first
6      A5     10  21  11  1
1      A5     11   5  21  5
2      A2      7  32  23  3
1      A2      8   4   7  8
       A3      5   6   9  6
2      A3      1   1   1  1
4      A4      2   2   2  2
1      A4      3   3   3  3
       A1      4   4   4  4
2      A1      5   5   5  5
```

I want

`df2.swaplevel(0,1)`

```
               A   B   C  D
second first
1      A1      4   4   4  4
       A2      8   4   7  8
       A3      5   6   9  6       
       A4      3   3   3  3
       A5     11   5  21  5
2      A1      5   5   5  5
2      A2      7  32  23  3
2      A3      1   1   1  1
4      A4      2   2   2  2
6      A5     10  21  11  1
```

Comment: `df2.swaplevel(0,1).sort_index(level=[0,1])
`

Comment: Thank you. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Thanks, your question is very well written and of great quality. Unfortunately it has been asked before so I've marked it as duplicate instead, but that doesn't mean your question is bad.

Comment: @MathWannaBe456 no worry , happy coding

Comment: @cs95 I understand. I will say however, if that question answers mine it doesn't appear very clear to a noob like me.